# sed not matching special alphabetic characters with dot (.)

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I'm trying to use sed to remove tags from a huge corpus (over 2M lines), but it's not matching special alphabetic characters (e.g. ã ẽ é ó) with the 'any character' regex (.)

Sample from corpus:

```
<ext id=1 cad="Opinião" sec="opi" sem="94a">
PT no governo  
Gilberto Dimenstein  

BRASÍLIA Pesquisa Datafolha publicada hoje revela um dado supreendente: recusando uma postura radical, a esmagadora maioria (77%) dos eleitores quer o PT participando do Governo Fernando Henrique Cardoso .
```

I wanna delete all tags (they all follow the same structure with "ext id=[0-9] cad" etc.), so I was trying to use

```
sed 's/<.\+>//g' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

It worked wonders for most of them, but I still got some remaining because of the special alphabetic characters I mentioned. What should I do?

Comment: The code works for me on your sample input.  Can you show an example of the code failing?  Show both the input you used and the output. you received.

Comment: Your locale settings and the encoding of the file would be importabt details to add. Specifically, in the `C` locale, each byte counts as an individual character, but if the file uses a multibyte or variable-length encoding like UTF-8, the non-ASCII characters occupy multiple bytes.

Comment: Parsing or editing XML/HTML using regular expressions can be very fragile. The usual advice is to use an XML specific parser.

Comment: @John1024 the sample input is an example of failure, it's one of the cases where it didn't work (got the same output as the input). maybe it's because of the encoding?

Comment: @tripleee i altered the encoding and it worked! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, possibly the simplest approach is to use the `[^>]` character class to match the content of the tag:

```
sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

---

This has an added benefit of matching only the tag content, where the original regexp would delete from the start of the first tag right through to the end of the last tag.  For example, given

```
foo <a...> bar <b...> baz
```

the original expression will replace `<a...> bar <b...>`:

```
foo  baz
```

but this one will replace `<a...>` and `<b...>`:

```
foo  bar  baz
```

Comment: @TobySpeight well, code of this length requires no explanation, and there is no magic here. I answered this question just for solving the problem, not for educating people. I'm sorry.

Comment: I've added an explanation for you.  HTH